# How to remove extra spaces in between two lines in enumerate and itemize?

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I am using `enumerate` and `itemize` as follows shown in my MWE. The output I get is shown in the figure mentioned below.

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\title{some text}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item \textbf{some text}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item[] some text
\item[] some text
\end{itemize}
\item \textbf{some text}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item[] some text
\item[] some text
\end{itemize}
\item \textbf{some text}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item[] some text
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to remove the extra spaces it takes in between the two lines?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Option `noitemsep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
From the page 12 of the manual:
```

> The key `noitemsep` kills the space between items and paragraphs
>   *(i.e., `itemsep=0pt` and `parsep=0pt`)*, while `nosep` kills all vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\title{noitemsep}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item \textbf{noitemsep}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item[] noitemsep
\item[] noitemsep
\end{itemize}
\item \textbf{noitemsep}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item[] noitemsep
\item[] noitemsep
\end{itemize}
\item \textbf{noitemsep}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item[] noitemsep
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: noitemsep]

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}
    \title{nosep}

    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,nosep]
    \item \textbf{nosep}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,nosep]
    \item[] nosep
    \item[] nosep
    \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{nosep}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,nosep]
    \item[] nosep
    \item[] nosep
    \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{nosep}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,nosep]
    \item[] nosep
    \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image: nosep]

#### It is possible to factor these recurring calls:

with `\setlist{leftmargin=*, noitemsep}` or `\setlist{leftmargin=*, nosep}`

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*, noitemsep}

\begin{document}
\title{noitemsep}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{noitemsep}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] noitemsep
\item[] noitemsep
\end{itemize}
\item \textbf{noitemsep}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] noitemsep
\item[] noitemsep
\end{itemize}
\item \textbf{noitemsep}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] noitemsep
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```